# Socket wrapper with events

Tags: c#, sockets, events, wrapper

How would one design a class for server, which is managed by simple client messages, in a proper way? This server uses event model to inform parent application about client requests. It uses asynchronous sockets. Server load is probably very limited.

This is what I would try:

```
class Client
{
private Socket sock;

public event EventHandler Start;
public event EventHandler Stop;
public event RequestEventHandler Request;

public Client(TcpClient Client)
//sock.BeginReceive

private void OnReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
//Dissect incoming stream into messages
//Call event handlers
//sock.BeginReceive

public void AnswerRequest(byte[] answer) //either this way or
private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)     //direct call of sock.BeginSend
}

class Server
{
private TcpListener Listener;
public List<Client> Clients;

public event EventHandler ClientConnected;

public Server(int port)
//Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient

private void AcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
//Get TcpClient
//Create new Client with TcpClient as a parameter
//Launch ClientConnected, where one should sign for Client events
//Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving this to programmers.stackexchange.com , conceptual design seems to be more correct there than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using nito async library, it has simpleserversocket and simple client.
very easy to use.
[Nito Async](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Quite short answer, but while trying to go deeper, I've stumbled upon a nice pattern in Nito code headlined "Standard way of translating an IAsyncResult-based notification to event-based notification". That made my day, thanks )

Answer (score 0):

```
   How would one design a class for server, which is managed by simple client messages,
   in a proper way?
```

It depends on which I/O Strategy be used. There are several different conventions for communicating with Winsock, and each method has distinct advantages.

- Blocking sockets
- Pure Non-blocking sockets
- Asynchronous sockets
- select()
- Event objects
- Overlapped I/O

Class Design for Asynchronous client Sockets : 
 Add Stateobject with your callbacks. Reading data from a client socket requires a state object that passes values between asynchronous calls.

```
          public class StateObject 
         {
            public Socket workSocket = null; 
            public const int BufferSize = 256;   
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         }
```

Source : [See msdn sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx) for detailed design.